# this simple code is giving me hard syntax error, divisor code

Tags: python, int, rounding

```
def main():
    user_number = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    num = user_number//2
    round(num,0)
    int(num)
    print(num)
    divisor = 1
    for divisor in range(divisor,num):
        if num%divisor == 0:
                print(divisor)

while True:
    main()
```

The syntax error I'm getting: *TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*

Comment: That's *not* a syntax error. `range` only accepts integer arguments, and you don't actually *assign* e.g. `int(num)` to anything.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You should write `num = int(num)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `num = user_number // 2` is a float.

The call `round(num, 0)` does nothing because you don't store the result in the `num` variable. Anyway, the result is a `float`. You should write `num = int(num)` instead.

Comment: I guess that the issue in the code within the question is the expectation that `x // y` should always return an integer. However, if `x` is a float to start with, then the result will be a float as well.

Comment: From the [Python PEP](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator) that introduced it: "A new operator, //, is the floor division operator. (Yes, we know it looks like C++’s comment symbol.) // always performs floor division no matter what the types of its operands are, so 1 // 2 is 0 **and 1.0 // 2.0 is also 0.0.**"

Comment: 100% agree: *user_number* is a `float` here.